Knapsack with fixed number of bins?
Constant: d, a fixed number of bins/sacks
Input:
$v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ item profits,
$0<w_1,w_2,...,w_n\leq1$ item weights.
Output: $B_1,B_2,...,B_d$ which are d subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ s.t. they are disjoint,
and such that
$\forall i\in\{1,2,...,d\}:\sum_{j\in B_i}w_j \leq1.$
Objective function: Maximize $\sum_{i=1}^d\sum_{j\in B_i}v_j$.
Looking for an efficient PTAS. That is, for every $\epsilon>0$ we should have an $(1-\epsilon)$ approximation using $f(\epsilon)n^{O(1)}$ where $f$ is any function.
TLDR: An EPTAS for multi-knapsack problem with fixed number of knapsack. I'd also prefer a solution based on rounding and dynamic programming.
The problem is that even if I knew what items are used for the solution, I'd still fail to find the actual solution since bin-packing wouldn't be efficient...
I considered starting from one knapsack sized d. I found, online, EPTAS for the generalized Multiple knapsack problem, but I'd prefer a simpler solution to a simpler problem.
